# Apex Class and Apex Trigger is invisible in Salesforce Developer Console

Tags: salesforce, apex, apex-code, developer-console, salesforce-communities

I want to write a Apex code and debug. I logged-in Salesforce and inside Salesforce Developer Console, Apex Class and Apex Trigger is invisible. I am not able to click that.

Path : Salesforce Developer Console > File > New > Apex Class / Apex Trigger

Comment: Do you have Author Apex permission?

Comment: You do realise that you can't write code straight in production org? You need to write in a sandbox or Developer Edition and then deploy to target

Comment: David Reed How can I set that? I'm new to Salesforce. Please help me out on this. I'm stuck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need create a new account in salesforce to developers, the account which you uses is a production account, the production accounts don´t have permissions to create a new Apex class and Triggers, i let the link to signup developer  account in salesforce bellow. 
[here](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/index_Left.htm)
I hope this comment help you.